# Simple UDP link

Tags: java, android

Hallo I need to write a very simple app that sends and retrieve data trough an UDP link (on **Android OS**, **API level > 18**):

This's a piece of code I used in an application I wrote sometime ago to connect trough TCP/IP (and doing the same thing):

```
class LinkReader implements Runnable
{
   private final int mPort;
   private final String mAddress;
   private final Socket mLinkSocket;

   public LinkReader(String address, int port, Socket link_socket)
   {
       mLinkSocket = link_socket;
       mPort = port;
       mAddress = address;
   }

   @Override
   public void run()
   {
       try {
           BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader(
                           mLinkSocket.getInputStream()
                   )
           );

           while (true)
           {
               Thread.sleep(100);
           }
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}

class LinkThread implements Runnable {
   private final int mPort;
   private final String mAddress;
   private Socket mLinkSocket;

   public LinkThread(String address, int port, Socket socket)
   {
       mLinkSocket = socket;
       mPort = port;
       mAddress = address;
   }

   @Override
   public void run()
   {
       try
       {
           mLinkSocket = new java.net.Socket(
                   InetAddress.getByName(mAddress),
                   mPort
           );

           new Thread(new LinkReader(mAddress,mPort,mLinkSocket)).start();
       }
       catch (UnknownHostException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       catch (IOException e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}

private void sendCommand(String cmd, Socket socket)
{
   try
   {
       PrintWriter _out = new PrintWriter(
               new BufferedWriter(
                       new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()
                       )
               ),
               false
       );
       _out.print(cmd);
       _out.flush();
   }
   catch (UnknownHostException e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

I've not been able to find an example about UDP connection on Android OS and I tought to reuse this code mainly because it was working pretty good (but I have to admint that I had not a very deep knowlede of Android neither I had very hight performances expectations from this piece of code).

Besides it was working in my past application my question is it correct *now*, in terms of code structure and *aging*?

How can I modify this to establish an UDP connection?

BTW Up to now I don't need really a R/W connection (I just need to send commands over there).

Comment: The UDP protocol is based in messages instead of streams, the information is not reliable and dont keep order of packages. Dont remember exactly the impl (in Java) but its about constructing DataPackages and sending to an address totally async.

Comment: I know how UPD works but it's over my control to select the protocol since the remote *server* is able to receive just those type of data.

Comment: UDP is the protocol, it works on messages instead of streams. You can search for any UDP in Java to see if it works in Android

Comment: good hint. thnx